# Connection refused when using Selenium & RSpec for rails JS testing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

I am running tests that starts by logging in a user using the login form. It successfully opens Firefox, navigates to the login form and fills in the fields, but when it clicks the 'Login' button, it hangs indefinitely. When I quit Firefox I get the following message on the failed test:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED:
        Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 7055
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**Edit:**

- Rails 4.2.0
- Ruby 2.2.4
- Capybara 2.6.2
- Selenium-Webdriver 2.53.0
- Firefox 46.0.1
- Using Capybara with RSpec
- `Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium`

**/spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  require 'simplecov'
  SimpleCov.start 'rails'

  require 'capybara/rspec'
  require 'aasm/rspec'

  RSpec.configure do |config|

    config.include Capybara::DSL

    def test_sign_in(user)
      # helper method to sign in the passed-in user
      visit root_path
      within(".user-login") do
        fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
        fill_in 'Password', with: 'foobar11'
        click_button 'Sign in'
      end
    end

    def test_partner_sign_in(partner)
      # helper method to sign in the passed-in partner
      visit root_path
      within(".partner-login") do
        fill_in 'Email', with: partner.email
        fill_in 'Password', with: 'foobar11'
        click_button 'Sign in'
      end
    end

    def js_test_sign_in(user)
      # helper method to sign in the passed-in user
      visit new_user_session_path
      fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
      fill_in 'Password', with: 'foobar11'
      click_button 'Sign in'
    end

    def js_test_partner_sign_in(partner)
      # helper method to sign in the passed-in partner
      visit new_partner_session_path
      fill_in 'Email', with: partner.email
      fill_in 'Password', with: 'foobar11'
      click_button 'Sign in'
    end

    config.before(:suite) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
      DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    end

    config.before(:each, js: true) do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
      expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
    end

    config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
      mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
    end
  end

  Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
end
```

**/rails_helper.rb**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'devise'
require 'controller_macros'
require 'byebug'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

**/test.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Configure static asset server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
  config.serve_static_files  = true
  config.static_cache_control = 'public, max-age=3600'

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # For Devise
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

**.rspec**

```
--color
--require spec_helper
--drb
```

Comment: What version of rails are you using?  Is there anything relevant in your test.log?  What is your capybara configuration?  What server are you using with Capybara?

Comment: I added some info above, I didn't see anything relevant in test.log. I haven't adjusted any capybara config. I'm not sure what you mean by what server I'm using, sorry.

Comment: What versions of Capybara, selenium-webdriver and firefox are you using?

Comment: @TomWalpole I added this information as well, thanks again

Comment: Those versions should work together, are you sure you haven't left any debugging (byebug, binding.pry, etc) statements in your code?

Comment: I do use byebug, but it is not currently in any spec files. Is there anything else I can share with you that might shed some light on this? I am using Spork, would that affect it?

Comment: You could add your rspec config, which might show something (also the test that is hanging).  I guess Spork could affect something, although I don't use it so not really sure what would be right or wrong about its config.  Barring leftover debugging statements or a test that has an endless loop in it, I'm not really sure what else would cause your issue -  the error you posted would be expected when you quit firefox since selenium-webdriver can no longer talk to firefox, but why the test never ends without that is the real question.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. I added a few files that have config options in them, please let me know if there's anything else I can provide that might offer some insight. The code that it is getting hung up on is the `js_test_sign_in(@user)` function which is in spec_helper.rb.

Comment: If your app makes use of its own API and any of the controller actions you're calling from your test make other requests to the same app you could try upgrading to Capybara 2.7.1 and specifying `Capyara.server = :puma` to see if that helps.  Otherwise my last suggestion would be to try disabling spork and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Ok, yeah I don't think I'm doing that at all, but I'll try seeing if disabling spork does anything. Thanks again

Comment: Were you able to fix it? I am getting the same error for all the Rspecs where `:js => true`. Earlier it was working perfectly fine, but dunno which update broke this.

Comment: No I was never able to fix it and eventually gave up, unfortunately. If you come across anything I would really appreciate you sharing it!